# Need help in removing ellipes (...) from a file using shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Need help in removing ellipes (`…`) from a file using shell script. I used `sed` command in various forms, but it doesn't help when running in a Unix box.

Following commands were used but didn't help when running it in a unix server.

```shell
sed 's/…//g' $x >> $x.tmp
sed 's/\.\.\.//g' $x >> $x.tmp
awk '{gsub(/\.\.\./,"", $0); print}' "Input.TXT" > Output.txt
```

- `$x` is just the file name.
- ANSI hex value for ellipses is `0x85` and Unicode hex value is `U+2026` and Unicode number is `8230`
- I tried the `sed` command with `\u2026`

  ```
  sed 's/\u2026//g' $x >> $x.tmp
  ```

  but it didn't help either.
- Sample input:

  ```
  …ABC
  …DEF
  …123
  …456
  ```
- Excepted output:

  ```
  ABC
  DEF
  123
  456
  ```

Its something within the unix server where the ellipses i.e. the three dots `…` is not being read correctly. If I `vi` (view) the original file from unix terminal, I see these ellipses as `<85>` and greyed out, whereas the other texts are appearing normally in black text like below.

```
<85>ABC
<85>DEF
<85>123
<85>456
```

Comment: What does it mean it "didn't help"? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead? Did you get any errors? What would an example input file and the corresponding output file look like?

Comment: And example input would be like 
…ABC
…DEF
…123
…456

And the output should be like|
ABC
DEF
123
456

But using the commands listed, I get the output same as in the input without the ellipses (...) being removed.

Comment: What is the value of `$x`? Can you add a hexdump of the ellipsis to make sure it's `...` and not `…` or something similar?

Comment: well, ok, `echo '…ABC …DEF …123 …456' | sed 's/…//g'` gives me `ABC DEF 123 456`, which seems about right? I copypasted the input from your comment, and the sed command from your post above. I'm not sure if what you have there is actually `…` (the single character U+2026), or `...` (three regular dots). I got the former from the comment, but it might be that SE formatting or something else messes it up. Which is why it's rather important to [edit] information like that in your post, and use code block formatting to make it clear which part is the actual data etc. (It still breaks tabs, though)

Comment: $x is just the file name. 
ANSI hex value is 0x85
and Unicode hex value is U+2026
and Unicode number is 8230

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output to your question by using the [edit] button, don't add it in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: $x is just the file name. 

ANSI hex value is 0x85
and Unicode hex value is U+2026
and Unicode number is 8230

I tried the sed command with \u2026 (sed 's/\u2026//g' $x >> $x.tmp) but it didn't help either.

Its something within the unix server where the ellipses i.e. the three dots … is not being read correctly. If I vi (view) the original file from unix terminal, I see these ellipsed as <85> and greyed out, whereas the other texts are appearing normally in blank.

Comment: Don't add explanations in comments either - put all information in your question.

Comment: When you say UNIX box, is this an actual UNIX and, if so, which one? Or do you mean Linux?

Comment: Yes Bog, this is resolved using your recommendation: sed 's/'$(printf "\x85")'//g' $x >> $x.tmp thanks for your support and assistance.

Comment: @HariramakrishnanBalusamy perfect, you are welcome^^ Also don't forget to mark the question as done by accepting an answer (the checkmark on the left side of the answer) :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the right answer, but worth a shot. You said that you already tried `sed` with `…`, but what if it shows a `…` but really isn't a `…`, as you saw that in `vim` it is the character `0x85`. Try this, does it work?:

```bash
sed 's/'$(printf "\x85")'//g' $x >> $x.tmp
```

Comment: Hi Bog, 

The below command seems to work fine, let me try with large files and comeback if any any issues.

sed 's/'$(printf "\x85")'//g' $x >> $x.tmp

Thanks all for your help; will test with above command and revert.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy/paste the same `…` from your input file into your sed command, e.g. if we use the sample input file from your question:

```
$ cat file
…ABC …DEF …123 …456
$ read -n1 chr < file
$ sed "s/$chr//g" file
ABC DEF 123 456
```

To see what those `…` are (they are NOT 3 `.`s):

```
$ cat -A file
M-bM-^@M-&ABC M-bM-^@M-&DEF M-bM-^@M-&123 M-bM-^@M-&456$

$ echo sed 's/…//g' file | cat -A
sed s/M-bM-^@M-&//g file$

$ od -c file
0000000 342 200 246   A   B   C     342 200 246   D   E   F     342 200
0000020 246   1   2   3     342 200 246   4   5   6  \n
0000034

$ echo sed 's/…//g' file | od -c
0000000   s   e   d       s   / 342 200 246   /   /   g       f   i   l
0000020   e  \n
0000022
```

According to https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ascii-table-hex-to-ascii-value-character-code-chart-2/, though, you must be using this character for the ellipsis if you're seeing `<85>` in your editor:

```
Decimal Hex Binary   HTML Number HTML Name Character Description
133     85  10000101 &#133;      &hellip;  …         Horizontal ellipsis
```

but if you just copy/paste whatever is in the input file into your sed command then you don't care what it is:

```
$ printf '\x85ABC \x85DEF \x85123 \x85GHI\n' > file2

$ cat file2
▒ABC ▒DEF ▒123 ▒GHI
$ read -n1 chr < file2
$ sed "s/$chr//g" file2
ABC DEF 123 GHI
```

Comment: Didn't he say he tried it?

Comment: @Borg it will work so they must not have tried it.

Comment: Yeah on my end it also worked. But then tell me why he said he tried it his first line of first code-block and also please explain me the `<85>` he sees

Comment: @Bog no idea, don't care. That's my point - if you just copy/paste whatever is in the file into the sed command then you can remove it without caring what it is.

Answer (score 1):

0x85 is the [windows-125x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) encoding of the U+2026 character, so that file is likely encoded in a Microsoft encoding.

You can either remove that particular byte value with:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\x85//g' that-file
```

But it might still leave other Microsoft-encoded characters.

You could also do:

```
tr -d '\205' < windows-file |
  iconv -f windows-1512 |
  dos2unix > unix-file
```

To remove those characters, convert the encoding to UTF-8 (replace windows-1252 with the actual encoding of that file), and fix the line-delimiters and other Microsoft quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/\x[2026]//;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -pe 's:g/\x2026//;'  file
```

*OR:*

```
~$ raku -pe 'tr/\x2026//;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.trans("\x2026" => "").put;'  file
```

Answers here assume you have  `…`, i.e. the single character U+2026. The first three answers use `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags. The first two answers use `s///` and show character can be properly identified as either `\x[2026]` or `\x2026`. The third answer uses `tr///` similar to answer two. The fourth answer uses `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags with the `.trans` routine, which takes a pairs argument.

Sample Input:

```
…ABC
…DEF
…123
…456
…
HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
Unicode: U+2026, UTF-8: E2 80 A6
```

Sample Output:

```
ABC
DEF
123
456

HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
Unicode: U+2026, UTF-8: E2 80 A6
```

Note: Instead of identifying the character by Unicode number, you can identify the character by canonical Unicode name, in this case `\c[HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS]`, for example:

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/\c[HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS]//;'  file
```

Using the canonical Unicode name can help with code-readability, for example when substituting punctuation characters like `\c[APOSTROPHE]` or `\c[QUOTATION MARK]`.

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#s///_in-place_substitution
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#tr///_in-place_transliteration
https://docs.raku.org/routine/trans
https://raku.org